# Make keyboard go over UI not shift the whole UI in UWP

Tags: c#, windows, xaml, uwp, win-universal-app

I'm building an app in Universal Windows Platform and I have put a `TextBox` at the bottom of screen but I don't want it to shift the whole UI upwards, and I don't want to reorder everything to be fit above the keyboard.

I just wanna do something like Cortana that the keyboard can be above all layers.

**What the app looks like itself:**

[image]

**What the app looks like after opening keyboard:**

[image]

**What Cortana looks like (which I want my app to be like this):**

[image]

```
<Page
x:Class="Pi.MainPage"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:Pi"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d" Loaded="Page_Loaded">
<Page.Resources>
    <FontFamily x:Key="Dekar">/Assets/Fonts/Dekar.otf#Dekar</FontFamily>
    <FontFamily x:Key="Consolas">/Assets/Fonts/SFThin.otf#SF UI Display</FontFamily>
</Page.Resources>

<Grid Background="Black">
    <Rectangle Margin="0">
        <Rectangle.Fill>
            <ImageBrush ImageSource="Assets/MainBG2.jpg" Stretch="UniformToFill" Opacity="0.35"/>
        </Rectangle.Fill>
    </Rectangle>
    <TextBlock x:Name="TitleText" Height="21" Margin="10,18,10,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="ADMIN ACCESS" VerticalAlignment="Top" Foreground="#FF00AEFF" FontSize="20" FontFamily="{StaticResource Dekar}" TextAlignment="Center" DoubleTapped="TitleText_DoubleTapped"/>
    <TextBox x:Name="CommandBox" Margin="0,0,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" FontFamily="{StaticResource Consolas}" Foreground="#FF8D8D8D" Background="#BF111E23" BorderThickness="0,1,0,0" FontSize="17" Height="50" PlaceholderText="Type here..." Padding="10,12,0,0" RequestedTheme="Dark" BorderBrush="#FF00AEFF" KeyUp="KeyPressed"/>
    <ScrollViewer Margin="10,65,10,60" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">
        <TextBlock x:Name="ResultText" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="What are your commands?" VerticalAlignment="Top" Foreground="#FFDEDEDE" FontSize="19" FontFamily="{StaticResource Consolas}" TextAlignment="Left"/>
</Grid>
```

Comment: I couldn't post more than 2 links so I've put a space after "https:".

Comment: Can you post your `XAML`?

Comment: Can you post your XAML code? I guess you didn't put your textbox and up side in same container?

Comment: It's something like this: There is a Grid (Main Grid), inside that there is the textbox and some other objects. I haven't separated the Grid with StackPanel or something else. Shall I?

Comment: If it's still needed to put the XAML code, I'll do it as soon as I access my computer.

Comment: @avk-naidu XAML added.

Comment: @fırat-esmer XAML added.

Answer (score 1):

By default the InputPane slides the page so that the focused element isn't covered by the keyboard. Your page has the focused TextBox at the bottom, so that has to slide up so the user can see what she types.

You can override this behavior by handling the InputPane.Showing event and setting the [EnsuredFocusedElementInView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.viewmanagement.inputpanevisibilityeventargs#Windows_UI_ViewManagement_InputPaneVisibilityEventArgs_EnsuredFocusedElementInView) property to let the InputPane know that you handled this and it doesn't need to slide.

You can move the TextBox to just above the InputPane's OccludedRect but leave the rest of the Page alone, then move the TextBox back in InoutPane.Hiding.

See

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.UI.ViewManagement.InputPane#events_
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/input-and-devices/respond-to-the-presence-of-the-touch-keyboard#handling-the-showing-and-hiding-events
- https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/keyboard-events-sample-866ba41c

Comment: Thanks for the answer.